# Transferring big data over Socket

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I currently try to send a big Message over a Socket-Connection. My Message has something about 1.3 MB. Here is my code:

```
public void send(String message) throws IOException {
  byte[] bytes = message.getBytes(encoding);

  ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);

  while (socketChannel.write(byteBuffer) > 0) {
  }
}
```

On the other side of the Client is a Sever, which just prints out the read data. It always stops reading after something about 260 kB. It seems to me that some Buffer is full? 
What can I do to make this Socket-Connection working?

Comment: Do you get any exceptions or what is happening?

Comment: No there is no Exception. ''socketchannel.write(byteBuffer)'' returns 262142 and he is stepping out this Method.

Comment: Is the channel in blocking mode? If it isn't, the code isn't valid.

Comment: You sure that the server end is working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (socketChannel.write(byteBuffer) > 0) {
}
```

If you aren't in blocking mode, this loop will terminate as soon as the local socket send buffer fills up, which causes `write()` to return zero.

A simple but poor quality fix would be to change the loop condition from `>` to `>=`. However if `write()` returns zero you should really be using a `Selector` and `OP_WRITE` to detect when the channel becomes writable again.

Comment: That's true I am in Non-Blocking mode. I tried to avoid the use of the Selector to Reduce the Complexity.

Comment: It may reduce the complexity but it also smokes the CPU pointlessly. They're provided for a reason actually.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to allocate enough space for your ByteBuffer and flip it before you send it, because you want to read from it from now on. Maybe this works for you.

```
final byte[] bytesToSend = message.getBytes(encoding);
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytesToSend.length);  
buffer.clear();  
buffer.put(bytesToSend);  
buffer.flip();  
while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {  
  try {  
    socketChannel.write(buf);  
  } catch (IOException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
  }
}
```

Comment: *Why* would it be better? wrap() delivers a flipped buffer.